# RSS feed has stopped updating

Tags: rss, feed

One of my users just alerted me that my RSS feed is 6 posts behind my website.

Feed is served directly by the WordPress install (didn't install Feedburner or anything), and located at http://www.thecontradictions.com/feed

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I found [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rss-feed-has-stopped-updating/) suggestion to use Health Check mode to turn off plugins and see if they are interfering, but if I turn off all the plugins, I can't tell if it's propagating to a user-only RSS feed to double check. Can someone break this down for me a little better?

Answer (score 0):

What did you add to your site to make the posts show up in forward chronological order, rather than the more normal reverse chronological order? Seems that whatever is doing that is incorrectly affecting your feed as well.

A blog is a series of posts in reverse order by time. Latest post first, basically. But your site appears to show them the other way around, from oldest first.

A feed isn't "updated", it's just another view of your site. Instead of showing each post on a webpage, it shows each post in an RSS feed. That feed also needs to be in reverse chronological order, so that new posts push old ones down. Because the feed isn't meant to show all the posts, only the most recent 10 posts or whatever you have it set to show.

So, whatever you have making it show the posts oldest first needs to be changed to not do that for the feeds.

Comment: Hey Otto, thank you! This confirms what I *just* discovered through the deactivate/activate plug-in method which is that it's the fault of the plug-in I'm using to display the posts in reverse chronological order this way. Following that rabbit hole, I found a possible solution on their support page (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/chronological-posts-with-php-not-a-plugin/). Going to try to implement and will follow up!

Comment: Okay, I *believe* I've resolved it by setting the feed to show more than the 10 latest posts. I think feed readers will interpret it correctly, but is that poor practice?